# Unable to link Flaticons in my ReactJs project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel

I am following [this](https://www.flaticon.com/iconfonts) official docs how to add flaticon in project, I have a project running on **php laravel** framework and using **ReactJs**

And in my project I was using font awesome.
This is my project structure ->

```
Project 
    >app
    >bootstrap
    >database
    >node_modules
    >public
        > css
        > fonts
        > images
        > js
           > app.js (Auto build/generated file during compiling)
        > scss
           > App.css (Auto build/generated file during compiling)
           > Flaticon.css (copied as per the docs)
    > resources
        > js **(Main resource of project)**
            > components
            > assets
            > pages
            > redux
            > **app.js**
            > route.js
            > services
        > lang
        > sass
        > views
             > **welcome.blade.php**
```

This is my **welcome.blade.php** ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Fly & Carry</title>
        <link href="{{asset('scss/App.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    // THis is my public/scss/app.css which is auto generated during compiling time.
    
        <link href="{{asset('scss/flaticon.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
    // ---> Newly added Link for flaticon css (Acc. to docs)
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_website_domain/css_root/flaticon.css"> 
    // What do I need to paste here in place of DOMAIN???
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="crud-app"></div>
        <script crossorigin src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" ></script>  
    // --> This is main resource JS file in whiich I am calling Routing and then pages of my app.
    </body>
</html>
```

please help me in this, I already wasted so much time, If you need any extra query I can provide you.
Any suggetion would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to fill `your_website_domain`, and you've already injected the flaticon css through blade syntax. You can remove the 2nd link tag for flaticon (the one you copied from docs) Only thing I can notice is that your file is named with capital F - `Flaticon.css` and you're importing lowercase - `{{asset('scss/flaticon.css')}}` - maybe try changing that?

Comment: Did you copy the font files along with the CSS? Usually the fonts also have to be in the same folder as the CSS

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me but I don't know, now it's running, I just close everything and re-start from fresh and it worked. And by mistake I type ```Flaticon.css``` , it was ```flaticon.css```  @Antonio

Comment: I didn't copy the font in the same file, as it is not necessary because all of my fonts are in separate Fonts folder. But still thanks for your suggestions. @abhigunwant Now it is working.